# Async handling gives unexpected results when using nested jQuery $.when

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

I've got a number of ajax calls that each triggers other ajax calls. I then want to await the latter in order to process the data from them. Here is the (pseudo) code: https://gist.github.com/2795435
The problem is that the callback function of the second `$.when-always` expression is triggered before all deferreds of the `promises2` array have been resolved/rejected. How can this be? As I see it, the first `$.when-always` callback will not be invoked until all deferreds of the promises1 array have been resolved/rejected and by which time all ajax calls for the `promises2` have been made and therefore should the callback of the second `$.when-always` not be invoked until all deferreds in `promises2` have been resolved/rejected.

Comment: Wall of text crits you for over 9000 damage. You die.

Comment: Looking your code, do you have a more "real" code?

Comment: Some traces of code will be an icing on the cake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that, in `await()`, jQuery fires `promises1`'s always callback before firing the callback associated with *last* `getJson` to respond. Thus, in `await()`, the `promises2` array is short of one promise when the inner `.when()` fires its always callback.

If I'm right then you should be able to run tests to show that (with one `.get()` per json reponse), in every case, all but one of the inner `.get`s (never more and and never less) will have completed when `doSomethingToTheDataStoredInSomeGlobalVariableBelow()` is called.

Whether I'm right or not, a workaround (not the only one I'm sure) would be something along the following lines :

```
function A() {
    var promisesA = [];
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
        promisesA.push( B(someUri) );
    }
    $.when.apply($, promisesA).always(function() {
        doSomethingToTheDataStoredInSomeGlobalVariableBelow();
    });
}

function B(uri) {
    var d = new $.Deferred(),
        promisesB = [];
    $.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
        someCollectionFrom_data.each(function () {
            promisesB.push($.get(someUriFrom_this, function(data) {
                extractSomeStuffFrom_data_AndStoreInSomeGlobalVariable();
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, promisesB).done(function() {
            d.resolve();
        }).fail(function() {
            d.reject();
        });

    }).error(function(){
        d.reject();
    });
    return d;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcdmz/) - with modified code to make it work as a fiddle.

Here (barring bugs), the array `promisesA` is populated with one `$.Deferred` per `uri` as before, but this time these Deferreds are not allowed to resolve automatically when their corresponding `getJSON`s resolve/fail. Instead, each Deferred is resolved "manually" when all of its associated `.get()s` have resolved/failed as managed with function `B()`'s array `promisesB` (of which there will be several instances each captured in a closure formed by `B()`).

This schema can be viewed as "downward" cascades of ajax calls (`.json()s` and `.get()s`) with reciprocal "upward" cascades of `.always()s`. (Mixed `.done()`/`.fail()`/`.always()` would be equally applicable.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested with one `.get()` per json reponse as you suggested but all of the get's did actually complete. Concerning your suggested workaround, wouldn't the `always`-callback in `B()` get invoked immediately since the `promisesB` collection at that point most likely would be empty (it's asynchronously populated so the `when`-expression will be executed before the `getJSON` call has invoked its callback)?

Comment: Dang, you're right. I'll see if I can come up with something better.

Comment: Have another look, I moved the `$.when...` structure up, inside the getJSON callback.

Comment: .... and added in `B()`, (a) an `.error()` handler, which causes `d` to be rejected should a getJSON() itself fail, and (b) a `.fail()` handler, which again causes `d` to be rejected should any of the promises in `promisesB` fail. Thus `d` is not left hanging under error conditions and (I expect) some memory becomes recoverable by garbage collection.

Comment: It works, fantastic! Funny thing was that it didn't work until I changed the `promises`-collections to be non-global, not sure of why not. Still don't understand why my initial approach didn't work though? Anyway, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm not completely sure what was wrong with your initial approach either. Never mind, it was fun making something that works. Have you tried introducing errors to check out the error handling? It should be robust but the behaviour may not be exactly what you might expect - it's in the nature of deferreds (and the way they are used here) that the first error in either `promisesA` or `promisesB` will cause `$.when.apply($, promisesA).always(...)` to fire and any incomlete `.getJSON()s` or `.get()s` will not contribute even if they subsequently complete successfully.

Comment: Yeah I got some bad request responses which caused `$when.apply(...).done` to trigger before all subsequent deferreds had been resolved/rejected which was why I switched to `.always` instead of `.done` which as I understand it only triggers when all deferreds have either been resolved or rejected.